# Bulk insert/export an array into a CSV file using PHP

Tags: php, arrays, csv, bulkinsert

I want to export an associative array into a .csv file. I'm using [fputcsv()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php) inside a foreach loop to insert the rows one at a time.

Here's my code:

```
$headers = array("Parent ID", "Company Name", "Created By", "Created Time", "Mandatory", "Valid", "Total Count", "Audit");

    foreach ($cursorCount as $eachCursorCount) {
        foreach ($cursor as $eachCursor) {
            if ($eachCursorCount["createdBy"] == $eachCursor["createdby"]) {
                $insertVal = array(
                    "parentid" => $eachCursor['parentid'],
                    "companyName" => $eachCursor['companyname'],
                    "createdby" => $eachCursor['createdby'],
                    "createdtime" => date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $eachCursor['createdtime']->sec),
                    "mandatory" => $eachCursor['mandatory'],
                    "valid" => $eachCursor['valid'],
                    "totalCount" => $eachCursorCount['totalCount'],
                    "audit" => $eachCursorCount['audit']
                );
                array_push($res_arr_values, array_values($insertVal));
                }
            }
        }
    }
    $fp1 = fopen('export.csv', 'w');
    fputcsv($fp1, $headers);
    foreach ($res_arr_values as $fields) 
    {
        fputcsv($fp1, $fields);
    }

    fclose($fp1);
```

Is there any method using which one can insert multiple rows at a time? (Or any other method with much lesser time complexity.)

Thank You.

Comment: i don't think there'd be that much of an improvement, because put simply: that function would have to run a loop itself. but instead of completely building your array and then iterating over it a second time, you could just push each data line as you create it. would cut iterations in half (not complexity, though) and **greatly** reduce memory usage

Comment: @FranzGleichmann Thank you for your suggestion. I should've thought about this earlier.
Coming back to the original question, is there no way I can reduce the time complexity of fputcsv() from O(n), where n is the number of rows?

Comment: just think about it: when you have to write 20'000 lines of data, you **have** to write 20'000 lines of data. you can't cut that short in any way, except you throw data away. when you have to work with each dataset, it is by definition impossible to get below O(n).. the only thing you can do is linear optimisation in terms of run time. (that said, with my previous suggestion, you reduce memory complexity from O(n) to O(1), since besides your input data, you only have to have one memory set in memory at any given time)

Comment: @FranzGleichmann Pardon me if my logic is absurd but I what I was thinking is to do something like appending multiple indices of array to string (say 20 per batch) in some csv accepted format and then inserting them in one go.
In that case, my number of insertions would've reduce to 20000/20=1000.

Comment: a) that's a linear improvement still leaving you with a complexity of O(n) and b) in exchange, the underlying function would have to do 20 times the work for each run. c) you *could* try buffering your CSV-data in memory before flushing it to disk to alleviate overhead of the underlying storage system, but usually the filesystem itself handles that pretty well.